# SHOW * FROM column in 10 minute period - mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a lot of data in a MySQL database, to make sense of it I want to pull it out in 10 minute intervals.

I can get the data from `lap_times`, but I'm unsure how to pull it out every 10 minutes, essentially I want to do the below (after the // is pseudo code).

```
SHOW * FROM lap_times // WHERE time is between 1370880036 and 1370880636 ?
```

Any ideas how I would achieve this?

Comment: What data type is the `time` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @start_time = CONVERT('2013-06-10 12:15', datetime);

SELECT *
FROM lap_times
WHERE time BETWEEN @start_time and @start_time + INTERVAL 10 MIN;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept the 10 minute blocks starting at the top of the hour rather than at arbitrary offsets then you can use logic similar to this:

```
SELECT SUM(col) FROM lap_times GROUP BY time - (time % 600);
```

Arbitrary offsets *could* be handled by subtracting them from `time` to move them back into the "rounded" time slots before using the `GROUP BY` clause above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide if you want your intervals to be "inclusive" or "non inclusive".

To me, it makes sense to make intervals "non inclusive" on the left and "inclusive" on the right... something like this:

```
set @t = 1370880636;
select *
from lap_times as lt
where lt.time > @t - 600 and lt.time <= @t;
```

If you want the interval to be "inclusive" on both sides, you can use `between`:

```
set @t = 1370880636;
select *
from lap_times as lt
where lt.time between @t - 600 and @t;
```